# How to add multiple data to a listView in a single line

Tags: java, android

I am trying to display in my list 3 data that are collected in the EditText. At the time of executing the button. If there are 3 fields to add, they are stored separately to me. What can I do in my code to make it unify as a single field in the list?
Example:
Name:Xerxes
Age:14
Description offense: When I was leaving school he spit on me.

When you hit the save button:

What you expect
Jorge 14 When I got out of school he spit on me (1 line in the list)
What is currently happening
Jorge
14
When I left school he spit on me.(3 lines in list)

This is my code:
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listView;
ArrayList list;
Button btAdd;
EditText etName, etAge, etDescription;
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

```
@Override                                                                            
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {                                 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                                              
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);                                          
    etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);                                   
    etAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);                                     
    etDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDescription);                     
    btAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btGuardar);                                   
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvList);                                 
    list = new ArrayList<String>();                                                  
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),                 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);                               
    btAdd.setOnClickListener(view -> {                                               
        String names=etName.getText().toString();                                    
        String ages=etAge.getText().toString();                                      
        String description= etDescription.getText().toString();                      
        list.add(names);                                                             
        list.add(ages);                                                              
        list.add(description);                                                       
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);                                           
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                                         
    });                                                                              
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can join the 3 data with a `String format()` and add only 1 item to list

Example:

```
String names = etName.getText().toString();                                    
String ages = etAge.getText().toString();                                      
String description = etDescription.getText().toString(); 

String stringFormatted = String.format("%s %s %s", name, ages, description);

list.add(stringFormatted);
```